# Implement a Command Object that changes a property on my viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I am trying to learn WPF/MVVM and for educational reason I create a simple application. I have some issues trying to implement a `Command Object`.

When a button control is clicked I want the background color of the Grid change to yellow using a `Command Object`. There are a lot of stuff about how to do this, but I want to do it with the clean way. Generally I want to achieve a loose coupling between `View`, `ViewModel` and the `Command Object` in order to test those classes.

Also i do not want to use some Libraries like `Prism` because I have the need to fully understand MVVM first.

I have a code sample but of course it does not have functionality. Just represented it for convenience  reason.

My view XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Calendar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calendar"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="480">

<Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColour}" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Button Margin="197,247,200,-239" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}">Color</Button>
</Grid>
```

My ModelView class

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    //Command part
    ICommand SubmitCommand;
    public MainWindowViewModel(ICommand command) {
        SubmitCommand = command;
    }

    //Data Binding part
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Brush backgroundColour = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("Red");
    public Brush BackgroundColour {
        get { return this.backgroundColour; }
        set {
            if (value != this.backgroundColour) {
                this.backgroundColour = value;
                var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BackgroundColour"));
                }
            }
        }
```

(it also has a data binding part but it does not have to do with my issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like not to have anything related to windows like colors(Brushes or Brush) in the viewmodel. Refer my below code.

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMNav_Learning.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMNav_Learning"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ColorConverterConverter x:Key="ColorConverterConverter"></local:ColorConverterConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColour,Converter={StaticResource ColorConverterConverter}}" Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Button Margin="50"  Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}">Color</Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyColor backColor;

    public MyColor BackgroundColour
    {
        get { return backColor; }
        set { backColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundColour"); }
    }

    public ICommand SubmitCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        BackgroundColour = MyColor.Red;
        SubmitCommand = new BaseCommand(Execute);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        BackgroundColour = MyColor.Yellow;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

public enum MyColor
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Yellow
}

public class BaseCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _method;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public BaseCommand(Action<object> method)
    {
        _method = method;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _method.Invoke(parameter);
    }
}

public class ColorConverterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MyColor color = (MyColor)value;
        switch (color)
        {
            case MyColor.Red:
                return Brushes.Red;
            case MyColor.Green:
                return Brushes.Green;
            case MyColor.Yellow:
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            default:
            {
                return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Subeamanian your provided code have a lot of stuff, give me some time to take a look and i will come back with questions.

Comment: at this line `SubmitCommand = new BaseCommand(Execute);` where it exists at `ViewModel` constructor, how the `ViewModel` know about the `Execute` dependency?

Comment: Refer the basecommand class, it is a common implemtation of ICommand, where you dont have to used a separate class to implement your commands. Suppose in a page if you have 5 button you dont have to create 5 classes to handle the click logic and also you can avoid passing viewmodel info to the command class. BaseCommand will have a action which will be invoking a method in your viewmodel. It is a slick way of handling commands.

Comment: Can I test `ViewModel` class with that `new` inside constructor?

Comment: Yes you can test the viewmodel. Since the command is exposed as property, you can do SubmitCommand.Execute on you test case to get the unit test done.

Comment: If i want a `ViewModel` CanExecute method to be invoked from `CommandObject` i have to pass it to the `CommandObject` contstructor? like `SubmitCommand = new BaseCommand(Execute, CanExecute);`

Comment: Yes, But you need to change the implemtation of BaseCommand to handle the CanExecute.

Comment: With your implementation, how can i raise the `BaseCommand` event `CanExecuteChanged` so i can reevaluate if the button must be enabled/disabled? I did a lot of research about this, and the only solution i found is to implement a new method at `BaseCommand` named `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` and then using `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` achieve the reevaluating. But `ICommand` does not declare a public method like `RaiseCanExecuteChanged'

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clearly stating your question, but I gamble it to be: *How to configure the command parameter for the viewmodel's constructor to have it change the backgroundcolour?*

Commands do their work by having them implement `ICommand.Execute(Object)` So basically you want to have the command object you pass to the constructor to have a method like:

```
void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        viewModel.BackGroundColor=Brushes.Yellow;
    }
```

This is awkward: the command is passed from outside the viewmodel, but it must have a reference to it to change its back colour. You may want to rethink your design.

Moreover: for the databinding engine to see the `SubmitChangedCommand` it must be a property:

```
public ICommand SubmitChangesCommand {get;set;}
```

Comment: ok, so lets ask again the question with a different form. How a button can change the Grid background color when it's clicked?

Comment: @dios231 How a button can change the Grid background color when it's clicked *using a command* ?

Comment: @dios231 So: add the question to your post!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a *public Property* for the `ICommand SubmitCommand` and you can use a private DelegateCommand in its getter/setter.